# How to structure a layout template in Haml

Tags: ruby, haml

I have a web page that uses Haml for layouts. "layout.haml" is a separate layout file which is used when rendering any actual Haml page.

layout.haml looks something like:

```
-# layout.haml
!!! XML
!!!
%html
  %head
    ...
  %body
    ...
    #content= yield
```

This is of course already in the document's `<body>` so manipulating things in the header is not directly possible. For instance `<title>` is changed via `@title`. A bigger problem is the fact that every page-specific JavaScript needs to be loaded in the body. Moreover,  layout.haml already contains JavaScript, so jQuery is usually instantiated multiple times.

Are there any suggestions for a better template structure?

Comment: For a HAML only app, with partials and layouts,  you should check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125265/using-layouts-in-haml-files-independently-of-rails

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This solution is for Ruby on Rails only:

You can use `yield(:location)` and the `content_for(:location)` methods. "[Using the `content_for` Method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method)" has more information.

layout.haml:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title= yield(:title)
    = yield(:head)
  %body
    = yield
```

view.haml:

```
- content_for(:title, 'My title')
- content_for(:head) do
  = javascript_include_tag :foo

%h1 My view!
```

Comment: Note that this is a Rails-specific solution.

Answer (score 6):

I use partials:

```
!!!
%html
  = partial('trst_sys/shared/html-head')

  %body{:id => "srv",:'data-lang' => current_lang}
  #main.wrap
    %header#header
      = partial('trst_sys/shared/header')
    %nav#menu
      = partial('trst_sys/shared/menu')
    %section#content
      %article#xhr_content
        = yield
      %article#xhr_msg.hidden
    %section#sidebar
      = partial('trst_sys/shared/sidebar')
    %section#main_footer.wrap
  %footer#footer.wrap
    = partial('trst_sys/shared/footer')
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check that out soon too