# Haml::Engine.render will not place content from block inside proper containing element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Let's first start with a code snippet to explain the issue:

```
= Haml::Engine.new('#bar= yield').render do
  this should show up inside div#bar, right?
```

Given that code and according to the [haml::engine docs](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html#render-instance_method) and more than one [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125265/using-layouts-in-haml-files-independently-of-rails), I would expect that the string "*this should show up inside of the div, right?*" would in fact end up **inside** the div#bar element, resulting in some html looking like this:

```
  <div id="bar">
    this should show up inside of the div, right?
  </div>
```

However, this is what I actually get:

```
  this should show up inside of the div, right?
  <div id="bar">
    0
  </div>
```

So, two questions:

1. Why does the content from the block show up outside div#bar and
2. What is that 0 inside the div#bar element?

Comment: You might want to ask this on the HAML google group: http://groups.google.com/group/haml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behavior of code your wrote. Let see for example:

```
- ['1', '2' ,'3'].each do |var|
    %div= var
```

`%div= var`  doesn't return as a result of block execution. It goes right in total html.

In your case:

```
= Haml::Engine.new('#bar= yield').render do
  this should show up inside div, right?
```

string `this should show up inside div, right?` renders as haml and goes directly into html to, and you block returns 0. That's why we see such result:

```
this should show up inside of the div, right?
<div id="bar">
    0
</div>
```

So, in your case you should do like that:

```
= Haml::Engine.new('#bar= yield').render { 'this should show up inside div, right?' }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying create a helper to wrap the HAML engine, you might need to do this:

**Helper**:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def generic_table(title, &block)
    template = File.read(File.join(Rails.root,'app','views', 'generic_table.html.haml'))
    haml_engine = Haml::Engine.new(template)
    haml_engine.render(Object.new, {:title => title}, &block)
  end
end
```

**View**:

```
= generic_table('Properties') do
  - capture_haml do
    Hello
```

I'd love to see a simpler way to do this

Comment: Note that if the OP had written the following (notice it is returning a string), it would also have worked as expected.

Haml::Engine.new('#bar= yield').render do
  "this should show up inside div#bar, right?"
end

.In other words, pay no attention to the "do" vs "{}", that's not important