# how do i dynamically change my format rendering engine in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

My default templating engine is haml, but I would to sometimes change it to erb if i specify a specific parameter?

For example, I am pasting in some html code and would just like to test the  code without HAML complaining about its format.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339130/how-do-i-render-a-partial-of-a-different-format-in-rails, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125265/using-layouts-in-haml-files-independently-of-rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do something like:

```
if params[:render_erb]
  render 'file.html.erb'
else
  render 'file.html.haml'
end
```

and call the action with ?render_erb=true

or

```
render "file.html.#{params[:render]}" ir params[:render]
```

and call it ?render=haml or ?render=erb (or nothing and it will use the default

at the end of the controller's action that you are using

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt switch to the haml version ever...
render "connect.html.erb"  OR
render "connect.html.haml"

Comment: I think it has to be render :file => '/path/to/file', note that it needs an absolute system path not a relative path and you'll have to specify :layout => true as well!

Comment: You are correct, please edit your answer above to have :file => ""

Comment: the :file => and the absolute path depends on the file you want to render, check here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong that you simply need to save file as `your_file.html.erb` instead of `your_file.html.haml`?

Comment: Well I did that but now it picks up my erb every time, I want that part to be conditional...  if X use HAML else use ERB??

Answer (score 0):

You can use different templates in the same application, and you can use different template engines for views, [partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339130/how-do-i-render-a-partial-of-a-different-format-in-rails), and [layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125265/using-layouts-in-haml-files-independently-of-rails), but as far as I know you can't duck in and out of multiple template engines within the same template file.

If you just want to drop some code in using a different template language, then I'd put it in a separate partial. That certainly seems easiest in this particular case.

Comment: I am not referring to using different engines in same template file, i just want to input a condition in my controller of saying "use erb version"  OR "use haml version"