# Including/importing HAML files using grunt-contrib-haml and Yeoman

Tags: haml, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-haml

I am currently using Yeoman with HAML (utilising grunt-contrib-haml) and would like to include HAML files to make things more DRY.

I am not that familiar with HAML, so after reading online it appears best to use =render, like so:

```
=render(partial="shared/ga")
```

however I am receiving the message that HAML lacks a native render() function:

```
Warning: Exception on line 75: undefined method `render' for #<Object:0x00000003474a98>
```

Is there a simple way to include HAML files from inside another HAML file, which will work with Yeoman/grunt-contrib-haml? and/or extending an existing HAML template to make things more DRY?

Comment: Switched to Jade (which makes this trivial) in the end and haven't looked back.

Comment: render is a Rails feature, not a HAML one. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125265/using-layouts-in-haml-files-independently-of-rails

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found that the simplest approach to this issue is to use js to import the files instead of the haml method. I'm using Angular.js so I can use it's imports and skip HAML's.

In the HAML template you write something like this (for Angular):

```
%div#publish{ng-include: 'views.someview', ng-controller: 'SomeCtrl'}
```

Works like a charm.