# Use HAML (for rendering partials) in a non-ruby environment

Tags: ruby, haml, guard

I am trying to use HAML (mainly for the rendering of partials) in a regular HTML/JS environment.

I'm using `guard` to watch the project, mainly for `.scss` files and also using Compass.

The project layout is:

```
-public/
  --assets/
    ---css/
    ---fonts/
    ---img/
    ---js/
    ---sass/
 --partials/
-src
  --partials/
    --- header.html.haml
    --- footer.html.haml
  --index.html/haml
```

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'rake'
gem 'haml'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'rb-fsevent'
gem 'rb-inotify'
gem 'sass'
gem 'compass'
gem 'sass-globbing'
gem 'compass-validator'
gem 'oily_png'
gem 'css_parser'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-haml'
gem 'guard-coffeescript'
gem 'guard-sass'
gem 'guard-compass'
gem 'guard-concat'
gem 'guard-process'
gem 'guard-uglify'
gem 'guard-livereload'
gem 'juicer'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Guardfile

```
# Compile stylesheet (compass watch)
if File.exists?("./config.rb")
  # Compile on start.
  puts `compass compile --time --quiet`
  # https://github.com/guard/guard-compass
  guard :compass do
    watch(%r{(.*)\.s[ac]ss$})
  end
end

# Minify CSS
guard 'process', :name => 'Minify CSS', :command => 'juicer merge assets/css/style.css --force -c none' do
  watch %r{assets/css/style\.css}
end

# Minify JS
guard 'process', :name => 'Minify application javascript', :command => 'juicer merge assets/js/app.js --force -s' do
  watch %r{assets/js/app\.js}
end

# HAML
guard :haml, input: 'src', output: 'public', run_at_start: true do
  watch %r{^src/.+(\.html\.haml)}
end

# Livereload
guard :livereload do
  watch(%r{.+\.(css|js|html?)$})
end
```

**THE ERROR**

The sass renders fine, as does the minifying, livereload, etc. And the haml compiles fine when I dont try to use `= render :partial => "header"`

The console output is:

```
$ bundle exec guard -i

Compilation took 0.105s
10:55:18 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
10:55:18 - INFO - Guard::Compass is waiting to compile your stylesheets.
10:55:18 - ERROR - HAML compilation failed!
> [#F8322E875F42] Error: undefined method `render' for #<Object:0x007feb43d1d8b0>
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

A similar issue is posted here: [Using layouts in HAML files independently of Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125265/using-layouts-in-haml-files-independently-of-rails).

I cannot however relate it well enough to my environment to solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Guard issue. The `render` method is defined by Rails, that's why you get the error.

That said you can find how to define it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6131411/304055 (the question you already linked).