# How to implement partials using HAML

Tags: haml, templating, partials

We are testing HAML and SASS on a recent project to speed up our development flow.

We built the static front-end, and from here, will be integrating the source into a Wordpress build. HAML isn't going to be used in the WP integration; we only used it to rapidly build the static front-end. However, not that it matters for this question, but we're using SASS throughout the entire build and into the WP integration. We're using Prepros as the preprocessor.

So, when building in PHP, it's pretty simple to use partials to make the front-end build more organized and efficient. No problem.

But we're using HAML on this project -- as an HTML generator -- and would love to integrate the language in all future builds if we can figure everything out. And we're trying everything possible to avoid having to expand into learning Ruby and/or configuring a complex development environment.

Anyways, using the overview above, is it possible to use partials to construct layouts in HAML without over-complexing the build? I've seen many answers relating to yes--and the answers are there--but the background information and semi-documentation just happens to never be there.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be absolutely amazing. Please know that I appreciate any effort and advice from the community!

Thanks again,

B

Comment: If you don’t want to use Ruby you might find you have a hard time using Haml, especially if you want to use partials or layouts since these both will involve Ruby code (note that they are separate things). You might want to look into the PHP ports of Haml.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using layouts in HAML files independently of Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125265/using-layouts-in-haml-files-independently-of-rails)